# MYSQL ignore where clause if variable is null

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, where-clause

I have a stored procedure which is taking in 6 variables which may or may not be null depending on the filters applied on the front end of my web project. However, currently this stored procedure is returning nothing even if the all the filters are set to null. I am using MySQL workbench if that makes a difference. Previously I had been using separate stored procedures depending on the filters applied but this was getting too hard to manage as I added filters.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `spFiltersGet`(IN jAlertId int, IN timeFrom timestamp, IN timeTo timestamp, IN seconds int, IN alertStatus varchar(255), IN jHostName varchar(255))
BEGIN 
DECLARE timeFromVal TIMESTAMP;
DECLARE timeToVal TIMESTAMP;
DECLARE fetchVal INT;
DECLARE offsetVal INT;
DECLARE alertIdVal INT;
DECLARE secondsVal INT;
DECLARE statusVal varchar(255);
DECLARE hostVal varchar(255);

SET timeFromVal = timeFrom;
SET timeToVal = timeTo;
SET fetchVal = 10;
SET offsetVal = 0;
SET alertIdVal = jAlertId;
SET secondsVal = seconds;
SET statusVal = alertStatus;
SET hostVal = jHostName;

SELECT * FROM job_alert
WHERE
(alertIdVal IS NULL OR alert_id = jAlertId)
    AND (timeFromVal IS NULL && timeToVal IS NULL
    OR start_time BETWEEN timeFromVal AND timeToVal)
    AND (secondsVal IS NULL
    OR time_diff >= seconds)
    AND (statusVal IS NULL
    OR status = alertStatus)
    AND (hostVal IS NULL OR host_name = jHostName)
ORDER BY alert_id DESC
LIMIT OFFSETVAL , FETCHVAL; 
END
```

If no filters are applied i.e all are set to null I am expecting this kind of output after I have converted it to JSON:

```
{
  error: "null",
  jobStatus: "SUCCESS",
  startTime: "Sep 9, 2016 10:42:54 AM",
  endTime: "Sep 9, 2016 10:42:55 AM",
  timeDiff: 1217,
  runCount: 2,
  jobInstanceId: 834,
  host: "IT2561",
  nextRun: "Sep 9, 2016 10:52:54 AM",
  jobCount: 11,
  name: "Gift Certificate Delivery",
  id: 6,
  description: "Gift Certificate Delivery"
}
```

I had written this from looking at other StackOverflow answers, so I'm assuming that there is just something that I have missed out. I do not get any errors in my console, it just returns no records.

Comment: Please share some sample data and some values you're passing and expecting the result set.

Comment: What do you pass to the variable if user doesn't select that filter?

Comment: @Shaharyar The default is when I'm passing all nulls into the sp and even then it isn't working so it would probably be easier to just say that they are all null. I've included json that I would be expecting but not sure what you really want me to include.

Comment: @Shaharyar if the filter is not set it passes in null.

Comment: You're missing the point here, `null` is a value and when you put it in WHERE clause you're asking mysql to search for the `null` values. Now when you pass all null you don't get anything because there's possibly no row with all values `null` in it.

Comment: @Shaharyar I am checking the variable I am passing in if it's null, not the records in the table? Unless I have misunderstood you.

Comment: Let me help you fix it, just share the schema of table `job_alert`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123151/discussion-between-justbecca-and-shaharyar).

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to fix it, without any data its hard to write a query. Check it and tell me if anything goes wrong. Also I've removed your variables, you don't need them:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `spFiltersGet`(
IN jAlertId int, IN timeFrom timestamp, IN timeTo timestamp, 
IN seconds int, IN alertStatus varchar(255), IN jHostName varchar(255))
BEGIN

    DECLARE _fetchVal INT;
    DECLARE _offsetVal INT;

    SET _fetchVal = 10;
    SET _offsetVal = 0;

    SELECT 
        * 
    FROM 
        job_alert
    WHERE
        alert_id = IFNULL(jAlertId, alert_id)   -- id
        AND 
        ((timeFrom IS NULL AND timeTo IS NULL) OR start_time BETWEEN timeFrom AND timeTo) -- start time
        AND 
        (seconds IS NULL OR `time_diff` >= seconds) -- min time difference
        AND 
        (alertStatus IS NULL OR `status` = alertStatus) -- status
        AND 
        (jHostName IS NULL OR `host_name` = jHostName) -- host name
    ORDER BY 
        alert_id DESC
    LIMIT 
        _offsetVal, _fetchVal; 
END
```